# Remote Viewing and Judaism

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, agada-stories-legends, sorcery-magic-kishuf

I’m fascinated to know if there are any kabbalistic ideas and/or aggadic references in chazalic literature that refer to or discusses the idea of “[remote viewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_viewing)” ( the practice of seeking impressions about a distant or unseen target, purportedly "sensing" with the mind).

Thanks!

Comment: The midrash (see Bereshit, parashat Chayei Sarah for example) discusses teleporting, which is not the same thing but not so far off

Comment: Can you cite that please so I can research it further? Thank you :)

Comment: Of course, @user! The citation is there in my comment

Comment: That’s not a citation. Is it in Midrash rabbah? About which verse in that parsha is it related to?